# How to infer the constant array type from its content?

Tags: arrays, typescript

If I define the following array:

```
const array = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

Its type will be `string[]`. How to infer the type from its content, to avoid the necessity to repeat array content in the type definition of `array`? I.e. this:

```
const array: ['a', 'b', 'c'] = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

Answer (score 3):

I found the simplest solution: `const` assertion.

```
const array = ['a', 'b', 'c'] as const;
```

The detailed explanation are [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions).

Comment: Most of the time you need to infer function arguments. Here https://catchts.com/infer-arguments you can find to do it without `as const`